How is the selected date being passed to the label?
I started this the code from this question.  I am in the process of modifying the code, to send the picked date to a cell and closing the calendar when that has happened.  I asked a previous question this code and incorporated those changes which seem to be working.
When I first launch the calendar, the date at the bottom follows this setting (yyyy/mm/dd):

After the date is selected, the date format changes to dd/mm/yyyy.
Question
Where is the bit of code that sends the day (calendar box selected) to label6?
What I have tried
Right now I am pulling the selected date from label6.caption.  This feels highly dependent on regional setting for dd/mm/yy, yy/mm/dd, mm/dd/yy.  I would much rather pass the date value to a variable then trying to pull it from a string.
PickedDate = Label6.Caption

Some research I have done
In the frmCalendar code I found this chunk of code which I do not understand despite reading:

MS Property Let
MS Property Get

frmCalendar Code snippit:
Public Property Let ShortDateFormat(s As String)
    SdtFormat = s
    Label6.Caption = Format(Date, SdtFormat)
End Function

Public Property Get ShortDateFormat() As String
    ShortDateFormat = SdtFormat
End Property

The part that confuses me about the above, is that I thought Date was a built in function for today's date and not a variable.  This is the only line where I found Label6.Caption being assigned a value.  I was expecting some variable instead of Date and the the variable to be set when a cell was selected.
frmCalendar Code snippit which is my best guess at where things are happening.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With CbLanguage
        .AddItem "EN"
        .AddItem "GER"
        .AddItem "SPA"
        .AddItem "ITL"
        .AddItem "FRE"
        
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With
    
    '~~> Hide the Title Bar
    HideTitleBar Me
    
    Me.Caltheme = Venom
    Me.LongDateFormat = "dddd mmmm dd, yyyy"
    Me.ShortDateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    
    '~~> Create a command button control array so that
    '~~> when we press escape, we can unload the userform
    Dim CBCtl As Control
    
    i = 0
    
    For Each CBCtl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf CBCtl Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve CBArray(1 To i)
            Set CBArray(i).CommandButtonEvents = CBCtl
        End If
    Next CBCtl
    Set CBCtl = Nothing
    
    '~~> Set the Time
    StartTimer
              
    curDate = Date
    
    thisDay = Day(Date): thisMonth = Month(Date): thisYear = Year(Date)
     
    CurYear = Year(Date): CurMonth = Month(Date)
    
    '~~> Populate this months calendar
    PopulateCalendar curDate
End Sub

The stack overflow question I pulled the frmCalendar from states the code was too long for posting so I have avoided doing that.  If there are specific sections of code I should look for and post let me know and I will update.

I also came from Turbo Pascal around 1992/3/4.
So, I feel you.
As for your question, the assignment of selected_date into Label6 comes at the highlighted places in the screenshots attached.
To find them, You can press Ctrl+F to search for "Label6.Caption" (exclude quotes) and select Current Project option_button under Search.
The following screenshot is the part where the final assignment of the selected date into Label6.Caption occurs when the ✔ button was clicked.
This maybe useful for you to suppress the msgbox from popping up upon button click and assign the selected date value to a specific cell/variable as you want.


In the screenshot below, the highlighted code is where the assignment to the label caption whenever each day's button was clicked, occurs.
This is NOT the part of the code to be edited to get the final selected date assignment.
This part is just to keep the selected date field to be updated (just for your information because it will show up when you search). But without this part, the msgbox statement would require a separate variable.

You can replace
MsgBox Label6.Caption, vbInformation, "Date selected"

with
PickedDate = Label6.Caption

if you want to store the selected_date value to a variable like you mentioned.
This code contains class modules and using userform as a class which maybe a bit advanced for the current you.
In the question that you referred to in your initial question, the last answer by michaelf, mentioned a calendar at the bottom of that post.
I used that one multiple times.
It has no API calls. This one you are using right now has some residual effects. So, I wouldn't recommend this one.
As for the parts that you don't understand about Property Let & Get, those found in the useform module are being used by userform-as-a-class, as this, kind of, encapsulates the userform variables inside the userform class.
Let is more or less equivalent to just assigning a variable like Let selected_date="30Sept2024" and you can actually write like that anywhere (not just inside a class).
Get is like getting a value out of a class(in this case, the defined userform class), like selected_date=frmCalendar.selected_date.
Property Get and Property Let as like tools for input and output into and out of a class module so that the data inside the class are encapsulated from the calling code, not usually used/required in normal code modules.
Feel free to ask me more.
Edit1:to accommodate OP's another thought like "to pass the selected date when it was clicked and close the calendar then rather then having to wait on the check mark to be pressed", I attached some additional code.

To add the new code below, you just press the blue area in the attached screenshot above and select Userform and in the dropdown window on it's right, choose QueryClose event.
QueryClose event is called whenever a userform is about to be closed, in this case, the Terminate event.
We usually write like CloseMode=0 if/when we want to check if userform was closed by X being clicked, however, in your case, the X button was intentionally hidden(by Win32API calls especially:SetWindowLong and DrawMenuBar), so it will never occur.
So we have to check if userform was closed from code by checking like CloseMode=1.
Info on CloseMode constants can be found in VBA help but offline VBA help was only available with Excel2010 (the version I always/now use for my VBA development).
All in all, the newly added code checks if userform is being closed and if so, it will printout Label6.Caption to Immediate window. You can replace it with your variable assignment like:
If CloseMode = 1 Then
  If Len(Trim(Label6.Caption)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please select a date first", vbCritical, "No date selected"
    Exit Sub 'or Cancel=1
  Else
    'Debug.Print Label6.Caption
    If isDate(Label6.Caption) then selected_date=Label6.Caption
  End If
End If

The red color line was just, that line being set as BreakPoint because I needed to see CloseMode value.
So glad to be able to help.
Warning!
I added extra code to help you accomplish your other thought.
However, please be mindful that such an approach like select a date and then Esc the userform has its own possible ramifications like, you showed the form, then you selected a random date, or, it will get assigned Today's date by default the moment the userform is shown, and then you forgot what you're doing (got distracted or something like that) and close the userform and this will result in a random date or Today's date got assigned to selected_date variable unintentionally.
The original code was designed specifically to NOT allow such incidences by explicitly inhibiting user from closing using X button and thereby, forcing user to actually press the ✔ button and thus required user commitment and acknowledgement.
Therefore, even though I showed how it can be done, I wouldn't recommend this approach.
But if you really think this is acceptable to you, please go ahead because it is my duty to inform you of possible pitfalls from using my code.

Thanks for that informative read!  "... may be a bit too advanced for the current you". understatement of the millennium!  I am still trying to wrap my head around objects, let alone classes!  I can usually read basic VBA subs and get what they are doing eventually and modify them to my needs but not always (case in point here).  I almost said BS to the line where label6 is assigned as I have commented that line out in my code.  However I replaced it with PickedDate = CDate(Label6.Caption).  However Label6.Caption gets called about 4 lines earlier at If Len(Trim(Label6.Caption)) = 0 Then

I missed the calendar class location of Label6 as I had only searched frmCalendar and CalendarModule.  I did not think to look in the Class module as I thought that kind of thing was not done in within the class module.  Just demonstrates how LITTLE I know about modules.  I am a work in progress.

The other thought I was having was to pass the selected date when it was clicked and close the calendar then rather then having to wait on the check mark to be pressed.  Thanks again for the digging and I will try and look at the other code you suggested in one of the other answers.

I just added some new code to help you "select a date and close the userform and still get the date in your defined variable without needing to press the ✔ button." And don't worry about the hurdles you're facing now. It was only about 5years after I started my HellowWorld in VBA, to finally be able to understand what classes/objects are. VBA is a beautiful and easy language to learn. And if you can read/understand/modify code to get what you wanted, you're like half-way there already.

Very helpful, and educational.  I downloaded the code you suggest in my first linked question.  Apparently that was about 6 hours ago and then I came into work so I have not been able to touch it only one cursory review of the code.  I will be heading  shortly and either getting some much need sleep, or I will start tinkering with the code again.

So I just downloaded the correct calendar today.  So glad I followed the one you linked.  Third times a charm apparently.

I'm very happy that you found my recommendation suitable. So nice to be appreciated. One thing I learnt throughout my little endeavor with VBA and programming in general is, to not to get stuck with something too steadfastly yet not to drop something too quickly and to know when to select which of those two choices. There are always other ways. Thank you for appreciating my assistance.
